# Exit from Total Algebraic mode in Spacemacs

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, help, calc

I started following Calc-mode tutorial in Spacemacs and I noticed that,
once we get in Total Algebraic mode(`C-x * c`, to start calc-mode, then `m t` to enable total algebraic mode) the way we should exit from this mode should be by using `M-m t`.

But it turns out that this key combo, in Spacemacs, has other meaning, calling other functions.

How can I exit from Total Algebraic mode(calc-total-algebraic-mode)?

Answer (score 2):

After analize the documentation of [Algebraic Entry](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Algebraic-Entry.html) I manage to find the reference to the original function and realized that, in fact, it just toggles the mode on and off.
Then, using the help system(`C-h f` `calc-total-algebraic-mode`) I could verify that the
keys binding to this function actually are `M-m m-t`.

So, to exit from the total algebraic mode in Spacemacs
we just need to call the same function using `M-m m-t`.